# JS automated click not working

Tags: javascript, triggers, automation

EDIT:

I think i have found a solution for this one. Might be a little primitive but inserting it here until someone comes up with a better solution.

Thanks !

```html
<html>
<body onload="makeShort()">

<p id="button" style=display:none; onclick="makeShort()">Click me.</p>


 
<span id="output" style=display:none; >Wait. Loading....</span>

 
</body>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function makeShort() 
{
   var longUrl=location.href;;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
      'resource': {
      'longUrl': longUrl
    }
    });
    request.execute(function(response) 
    {
 
        if(response.id != null)
        {
            str =""+response.id+"";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("error: creating short url n"+ response.error);
        }
 
    });
 }
 window.onload = makeShort;
 
function load()
{
    //Get your own Browser API Key from  https://code.google.com/apis/console/
    gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxx');
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="";});
 
}
window.onload = load;
</script>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('button').click();
       },1000);
</script>



<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>
 

</html>




<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function SendLinkByMail(href) {
                var subject= "Interesting Information";
                var body = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
                body += " Interesting Information";
                var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
                uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
                uri += "&body=";
                uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
                window.open(uri);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="javascript:(function()%7BSendLinkByMail()%3B%7D)()%3B">Email link to this page</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can some one suggest why this "auto-click" function is not working in my code below?

```js
    function makeShort() {
    var longUrl = location.href;;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
        'resource': {
            'longUrl': longUrl
        }
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {

        if (response.id != null) {
            str = "<b>Long URL:</b>" + longUrl + "<br>";
            str += "<b>Short URL:</b> <a href='" + response.id + "'>" + response.id + "</a><br>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;
        } else {
            alert("error: creating short url n" + response.error);
        }

    });}    window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('modal');
    button.form.submit();}    
    function load() {
    //Get your own Browser API Key from  https://code.google.com/apis/console/
    gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxx');
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', function() {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
    });}   window.onload = load;
```

```html
<html>

<input type="button" id="modal" value="Create Short" onclick="makeShort();" /> <br/> <br/>

<div id="output">Wait. Loading....</div>
 
<head>
</head>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>
</html>
```

My basic aim is to insert a "share via email" button on the page which would shorten the url on the address bar and open user's email client/whatsapp app to share that url..

Obviously I could not find a way to combine these two functions in to one since I am not a very experienced js person. The primitive solution I found is to auto-click the first function, get the short url, and then find a different code to insert this in to the body of the "mailto" link, which will be my 2nd challenge.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: The url shortener is working if you click the button, but i want the button to be clicked automatically on page load, which is not happening

Comment: I can't see any of your code which relates to clicking a button automatically

Answer (score 0):

**To programmatically click a button on page load**

If you are using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#modal').click();
});
```

Plain javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('input', true, true);
    document.getElementById("modal").dispatchEvent(event);
 };
```

Comment: i think this is not working because there is already a different onload function in my js maybe?

Comment: Yes you do. In your `window.onload` function, you are invoking a submit on your button. However the function `makeShort()` that you want to run is placed inside an `onClick` handler... to get this working the way you want to, just change where you're invoking the submit to the code that I have posted which invokes a click

Comment: I'm a bit unsure why you want to do it this way anyway.. why not just call `makeShort()` on page load and also have it bound to the button click as you already have? Seems wrong to be automatically clicking a button